How to read /L in english , like I this expression 4 x 109/L?
4 x 109/L  I need to know how to read this /L in this expression. Thx

Without any other information I think you would say (spoken out loud)

Four times one hundred and nine divided by L

Or it could be

Four times one hundred and nine slash L

Or, as Michael Harvey says in his comment

'4 billion per litre'

It does depend on context.

4 x 109/L does look awfully like '4 billion per litre' with the indication of power of 10 not shown, but, as you say, context is important.

@MichaelHarvey You are perfectly correct. As an engineer and mathematician I should have spotted that! I will add that to the answer.
